# Non Spring Cloud Stream (SCS) producer sending JSON message to SCS consumer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I've got a non SCS producer (app using Spring-Kafka) trying to send a json serialized object to a topic subscribed by a SCS consumer.

The message put on the topic is -

{"message":"hello world2","mobileNumber":"111111"}

The SCS consumer has the below configuration.

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.headerMode=raw

Below is a link to the StackTrace -
https://gist.github.com/ajaydivakaran/459b572140b14d581349b3eab5383f4d

The documentation says SCS supports receiving and sending payloads to non SCS producers and consumers. Could someone help me figure out what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I got the SCS consumer to work by changing the configuration to -
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.content-type=text/plain

Comment: Could someone clarify why the message ends up as a string even though a JSONSerializer is specified on the Spring-Kafka producer side?

Comment: Thank you - Two days trying to figure this out. This is not really intuitive.   You would think if the sending and receiving raw content types were application/json that it would just work.